# Method to download whole data directory from UCI ML repository

Tags: api

I am working on a [tool to manage data downloading](https://github.com/oxinabox/DataDeps.jl).

One source of data I would like to make easy to access is the [UCI ML dataset repository](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.php)

A lot (all?) of the data is in directories,
for example for the [Auto MPG dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/auto+mpg) the directory [is this one](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/)

Now it is possible to just download each file in turn, but that is inelegant.
And right now I can't even see a way to do that automatically without scraping HTML.

Does the UCI repo expose a way to download the whole dataset e.g. in a zip-file.
Or some nicer automate-able way, like FTP, that would at least let me avoid scraping HTML to get a list of URLs.

Answer (score 1):

This is not ftp but it is the HTTP directory listing. Sort of the midpoint between HTML and FTP but it might be what you are looking for.

http://mlearn.ics.uci.edu/databases/

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a task for GNU's [`wget`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273743/2327328), the open source vacuuming tool used mostly for websites. It's standard on Linux, and can be installed on Mac OS X as well as Windows, or as part of Cygwin. An alternative to wget would be [`curl`](https://curl.haxx.se/).

I would imagine you would create a list of all data folders, and then loop over each folder, running wget for each item in the loop:

```
wget --recursive --no-parent https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/auto-mpg/
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273743/2327328) for more details.

Or, if you can remove the `auto-mpg` sub-folder and then you'll really vacuum everything.

---

Programming languages may have ports of wget, for example for python

```
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wget
```

a pure python download utility

---

Statistical and machine learning programming languages may have pseudo-APIs with the UCI ML Repository.

For R, see for example [`readMLData`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/readMLData/index.html):

> Functions for reading data sets in different formats for testing machine learning tools are provided. This allows to run a loop over several data sets in their original form, for example if they are downloaded from UCI Machine Learning Repository. The data are not part of the package and have to be downloaded separately.

The [download_script.R](http://www2.cs.cas.cz/~savicky/readMLData/download_script.R) ([source](http://www2.cs.cas.cz/~savicky/readMLData/)) uses wget for listed data packages

Comment: Indeed, it looks like vacuuming https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/ gives all datasets.

Comment: I'm not keen to use `wget` (or `curl`), because they don't tend to come with windows and adding it as a dependancy would be too heavy weight. Looking at wget, it included  a 1200 line HTML parser for this purpose.I could do something evil by invoking [powershell shenanigans in windows](https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-invoke-webrequest-parse-and-scrape-a-web-page/) to do a `--recursive` but then it would break on all kinds of different windows setups. Or I could use a Html parse of my own (but that is a dependency). This might be a time when parsing HTML with regex is good enough...

Comment: what programming language are you using? using regex to parse html is usually not advised (joke: https://blog.codinghorror.com/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way/)

Comment: see here for getting standalone wget.exe with no libraries or dlls -- https://superuser.com/a/245567/442118

Comment: I'm using Julia, and in julia we have a bunch of great HTML parsers. But I am trying for minimal dependencies. Sure generally parsing HTML is bad because HTML is non-regular. But any finite set of documents is regular. And the format of the UCI pages is consistent (it is generated by apache) and don't do anything like include `href=".*?"` in the body or in comments. I'm not super happy about it though. So maybe just downloading wget.exe from somewhere is best